# Array + Curve modifiers - dealing with overlapped faces effectively

Tags: modifiers

Is there any automatic way to avoid overlaps in sharp curve angles you can see in the screenshot?
[image: ve]
I know I can manually select the area, delete faces and fill it using Grid Fill or so, but as I need to make countless of these, I will lose lot of time by such editing.