# Raked sand/gravel

Tags: particles, system

First time posting but long time lurker :) I'm trying to do a zen garden and I'm stuck in finding a way to model the raked sand/gravel surrounding the stones.
I'm not a pro and so far I've modelled a simple plane with a particle system taking a collection of pebbles previously shaped, this gives me a generic gravel effect. How do you think I can arrange this gravel in an orderly fashion just like the image, please?
Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Maybe use [this technique](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165827/using-a-b%c3%a9zier-curve-to-raise-lower-height-of-vertices/165831#165831)

Comment: Thanks for the input! it could work as a solution but this would create onyl the downward lines without accounting for the upwards mounds created by the movement of the grains.
Should I do it also on the oppposite face? I fear i might be too heavy on the file. What do you say?

Comment: You could probably adjust the midlevel of displacement, you can also assume it will only displace in one direction and compensate accordingly by adjusting object position so ridges and valleys with be at the desired height.

Comment: Thanks! I made a set of arrays and it looks quite good!