# I need to turn curve into a mesh using modifier

Tags: mesh

I need to turn curve into a mesh **using modifier** so i can work non-destructively, and be able to make boolean with curves without convert it to mesh then export curves to cnc

Here is the situation:
I'm modeling ornament with curves and when the client is happy with the result i need to send the curves to the cnc machine so it can carve on real wood.

[image]

Comment: You can't boolean with curves directly in Blender and you can't non destructively convert to mesh. See https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165827/using-a-b%c3%a9zier-curve-to-raise-lower-height-of-vertices/ for workarounds

Comment: thanks Duarte,
very clever workflow but it doesn't suite my situation because  I need to get benefit of curve custom bevel feature so i can simulate the carving bit
i think i need that modifier to be compiled :)
mean while i will convert to mesh, get client comments, modify the curve, reconvert to mesh and replace the old boolean

Comment: If your question has been solved, please be so kind and mark the answer that contributed to the solution as "Accepted answer". This will make it easier for others to see which path leads to the solution, and the question will no longer show as unsolved. Thank you! Here you can find more information: [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers). If you still haven't gotten a solution to your question, please be kind enough to address it.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this very easily with Geometry Nodes and the node `Mesh Boolean` (Blender 3.x):

[image]

If you want to use already existing curves in Geometry Nodes, just add them with the node `Object Info` and replace the example shown here.