# Drop racetrack into terrain

Tags: modeling, sculpting

I'm currently messing around with race tracks in blender and have an issue with how the track sits on the terrain (using a subdivided plane). I've used a shrinkwrap modifier on the track, which works well, however I'd need to stretch the track downwards to avoid the weird gap underneath the track. Ideally I'd like the track to somehow "push" the track downwards onto the terrain (instead of having to stretch it down), almost like using it as a brush in subtract mode. The desired effect is shown in the Mario Kart track image, while not exteme, you can clearly see the road part of the map is sunk a little between the terrain.

My track:
[image: Race Track]

Mario Kart track:
[image: Mario Cart Track]

If anyone has any idea how I can achieve this effect in the Mario Kart screenshot, (where the road meets the grass smoothly, and the road is slightly lower than the terrain) it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you edit your nurbs path to sit on the terrain instead of the mesh? Also, have you tried shrink wrapping your path instead of the mesh?

Comment: @Rug I have tried both shrink wrapping the track and nurbs path, and both. The main issue is I would like the track to "push down" into the terrain, like how you can use a brush in sculpt mode to push the terrain down. Achieving the effect of the terrain being a little raised around the edges of the track.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165827/using-a-b%c3%a9zier-curve-to-raise-lower-height-of-vertices

Comment: Thanks to Duarte's post (in the comments) I connected the track in the way I wanted. I used the Vertex Weight Proximity and Displace modifier on the plane mesh for the ground. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzOWK.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzOWK.jpg)