# creating a vertex group with "distance to another object" criteria (for a Mask modifier)

Tags: modeling, vertex-groups

I have a character where occasionally an underlying mesh (clothing or body) pokes through an "upper layer":

[image]

While I have used Surface Deform to get jeans to better deform over skin/body, it is never perfect (e.g., muscle bulge can poke through shirt or pants).   In the image above multiple layers get more complex.   I was thinking in this case that having a vertex group in the pants, that is *Masked* by a driver (bpy.data.objects["Shirt"].hide_render) might work.  I'd lose the deforming of the shirt by the pants, but I would suffice.

Getting the Vertex Group defined is my challenge, something that an operator like Shrinkwrap probably has built in.   While I could go the python route, am I overlooking a simpler Interface/"Select by distance to another object" that might define the selection?

[image]

Comment: Does the [Vertex Weight Proximity](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/modify/weight_proximity.html) modifier head in the right direction?

Comment: The trick I think you are missing is that you don't *create* a vertex group, you modify an existing one. See the *Vertex Weight Proximity* modifier https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/153177/worms-crawling-under-skin or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/165827/using-a-b%c3%a9zier-curve-to-raise-lower-height-of-vertices